# How to define a class and using data from outside

Tags: javascript, class

I have a class like this

```
class classname 
 {
  getuser(){}
  deleteuser(){}
 }
```

there are a list of users, defined out of the class like this

```
let user =[
 {id:1,name:"username},
 {id:2,name:"username},
]
```

Already I have a code with functions that work very well. But I have a problem accessing the list of users inside the class. Do I need to create a contractor?

Comment: _contractor_?  Did you mean _constructor_?

Comment: "*Already I have a code with functions that work very well*" - then what exactly is the problem? Why do you want to use a class?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to create a contractor?

Yes Of course it must, When you're dealing with ***`OOP`*** every `class` has `constructor` even you don't create it, it has by default!

> I have a problem accessing the list of users inside the class.

Try to declare it *before* and create your `User objects`, Then Add them up to the list of `users`, Play around with them by *getting* and *deleting*.

```js
class User {
  constructor(id, name, isVerified) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.isVerified = isVerified;
  }
  static getUser(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        let user = users.find((user) => {
          return user.id == id;
        });
        if (user) resolve(user);
        else reject("User not found!");
      }, 2000);
    });
  }
  static deleteUser(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        let user = users.find((user) => {
          return user.id == id;
        });
        if (user) {
          users = users.filter((user) => user.id !== id);
          resolve("User deleted successfully!");
        } else reject("user not found");
      }, 2000);
    });
  }
}
let users = [];
const u1 = new User(1, "Armin", true);
const u2 = new User(2, "Vahid", true);
const u3 = new User(3, "Steve", false);
users.push(u1, u2, u3);
console.log(await User.getUser(1)); //{ id: 1, name: "Armin", isVerified: true }
console.log(await User.deleteUser(3)); //User deleted successfully!
console.log(users); //[{id: 1, name: 'Armin', isVerified: true}, {id: 2, name: 'Vahid', isVerified: true}]
console.log(await User.getUser(3)); //User not found!
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend using values outside of the a class. The reason for this is that the class doesn't have a way to know if any values are changed or manipulated outside if the instance. Keeping the values as a part of the class will allow every instance to own it's own set of data. For example, you can help multiple sets of users that aren't related in any way, but should still be manipulated with the same methods.

If you need the class to handle the users, then you could pass the users to the class with a `constructor` or through methods of your own. For example: `addUser(id, name) {}`

In the example below I've chosen the latter.

You don't need a `constructor`. Only if you have logic that has to be called whenever you create a new instance of the class, like setting up values and properties.

```js
class Users {
  list = [];
  
  add(id, name) {
    this.list.push({
      id,
      name
    });
  }
  
  get(id) {
    return this.list.find(user => user.id === id);
  }
  
  delete(id) {
    this.list = this.list.filter(user => user.id !== id);
  }
}

// Create users instance.
const users = new Users();

// Add two users.
users.add(0, 'Foo');
users.add(1, 'Bar');
console.log('All users', users.list);

// Get a single user
const userBar = users.get(1);
console.log('User Bar', userBar);

// Delete a single user.
users.delete(0);
console.log('All users after deletion', users.list);
```